# BAREWORD filehandles: bareword "DATA" not allowed

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read some tgz data from the `__END__` section of  a perl script. 
I'm running into problem with the filehandle, sometimes using it doesn't cause a problem and sometimes the script throws an error.

Here's some example code, I know the data isn't tgz but it does show the problem.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $raw_time = (stat(DATA))[9];
my $size     = -s DATA;
my $kilosize = int($size / 1024) . 'k';

print "<P>Script size is $kilosize at $raw_time\n";

#print ref(DATA);    #UNCOMMENT TO SEE THE PROBLEM?

__DATA__
DO NOT REMOVE THE PRECEDING LINE.
Everything else in this file will be ignored.
```

If I run this script I get

```
$ /tmp/data.pl 
<P>Script size is 0k at 1500655490
```

DATA seems OK to use.

But, if I uncomment `print ref(DATA);` I get an error on that line:

```
Bareword "DATA" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /tmp/data.pl line 12.
Execution of /tmp/data.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Why isn't the use of DATA earlier also a problem?

[pre-post update] If I change the line to be

```
print "ref:". ref(\*DATA);
```

It doesn't throw the compile error. What's going on?

Comment: `stat` and `-s` are both file-related functions. They intentionally allow bareword filehandles. `ref` isn't particularly file-ish, so it doesn't. What are you trying to accomplish with `ref(DATA)`?

Comment: just trying to simplify the case where DATA  sometimes caused a compile error and sometimes didn't. the actual code ends up being my $tar=Archive::Tar->new(); $tar->read(DATA)   That gives the same error and \* "fixes" it

Comment: my $data_fh = \\*DATA; and use only scalar filehandle to avoid confusion.

Comment: The way to use typeglobs is either as `*FH` or `\*FH` -- unless they are passed to things that specifically expect a filehandle (In which case `FH` is fine).  By all means switch to lexical filehandles, per    [@Сухой27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B927)'s comment

Comment: is there a lexical filehandle solution for DATA? Is that even a reasonable question?

Comment: Very reasonable question, I'm hoping someone has an answer for it

Comment: Well that's what @Сухой27's comment shows -- that's one way to create a lexical (indirect) filehandle.  After that you can use `$data_fh` and you'll be working with `DATA`.  Note that you can't do it in a `BEGIN` block (as `DATA` has not been seen yet), but you can do it right at the program's start and then you have access to `DATA` via a "normal" variable.

Comment: @zdim But you can do it in a `CHECK` block.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Ah, a good point! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have explained what's going on. In contexts where `perl` expects a filehandle/fileglob, it is OK to use `DATA`. But, in a context, such as `ref(DATA)` where there is no *a priori* reason to assume that the argument is a file handle/glob, that does not work.

> is there a lexical filehandle solution for `DATA`?

I am not quite sure what you are after, but this might help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# You could use any variable name you like
my $DATA_FH;

CHECK { $DATA_FH = \*DATA }

print <$DATA_FH>

__DATA__
One
```